How to install osslsigncode on linux server (OL8 or RHEL8)
I need to sign my .exe file on linux, for that i am trying to install osslsigncode on Ol8/RHEL8 but not able to install
I have followed the below step to install
Obtain Fedora EPEL repository. It containsthe osslsigncodetool.
sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
Installed: epel-release-8-13.el8.noarch
Install the latest osslsigncode-2.2 for el8.x86_64
sudo dnf install osslsigncode.x86_64
Fedora repository is installed successfully but not able to find match for osslsigncode.x86_64 on installation.
